# how to get the number of occurrence of an expression in a file using python

Tags: python, json, regex, file, loops

I have a code that read files and find the matching expression with the user input and highlight it, using **findall** function in regular expression.

also i am trying to save in **json file**  several information based on this matching.

like :

- file name
- matching expression
- number of occurrence

the problem is that the program read the file and display the text with  highlighted expression but in the json file it save the **number of occurrence** as the **number of lines**.

in this example the word **this** is the searched word it exist in the text file   **twice**
the result in the **json file** is = **12 ==> that is the number of text lines**
[result of the json file and the highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJO0R.png)

## code:

```
def MatchFunc(self):           

    self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
    x = self.lineEditSearch.text()
    TextString=self.ReadingFileContent(self.FileListSelected())
    d = defaultdict(list)  
    filename = os.path.basename(self.FileListSelected())


    RepX='<u><b style="color:#FF0000">'+x+'</b></u>'

    for counter , myLine in enumerate(filename):

        self.textEdit_PDFpreview.clear()
        thematch=re.sub(x,RepX,TextString)
        thematchFilt=re.findall(x,TextString,re.M|re.I)


        if thematchFilt:
            d[thematchFilt[0]].append(counter + 1)


            self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml(str(thematch))

        else:
            self.textEdit_PDFpreview.insertHtml('No Match Found')        

    OutPutListMetaData = []   
    for match , positions in d.items():

        print ("this is match {}".format(match))
        print("this is position {}".format(positions))

        listMetaData = {"File Name":filename,"Searched Word":match,"Number Of Occurence":len(positions)}
        OutPutListMetaData.append(listMetaData)
        for p in positions:
            print("on line {}".format(p))                    

    jsondata = json.dumps(OutPutListMetaData,indent=4)
    print(jsondata)            

    folderToCreate = "search_result"
    today = time.strftime("%Y%m%d__%H-%M")
    jsonFileName = "{}_searchResult.json".format(today)

    if not(os.path.exists(os.getcwd() + os.sep + folderToCreate)):
        os.mkdir("./search_result")
    fpJ = os.path.join(os.getcwd()+os.sep+folderToCreate,jsonFileName)
    print(fpJ)

    with open(fpJ,"a") as jsf:
        jsf.write(jsondata)
        print("finish writing")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Once you pass an iterable, it returns each one of them along with the number of occurrences as tuples.

Answer (score 0):

As the `re.findall` function returns a list you can just do `len(result)`.